# The current workspace is using a new version of .NET SDK '8.0.100', which is not supported by current .NET runtime used by the extension

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Issue: My C# intellisense is not working in Visual Studio Code and auto import (using namespace) is not working too

.NET SDK version: 8.0.100

Visual Studio Code version: 1.86.1

Operating System: Windows 10 22H2

C# dev kit extension version: v1.3.10

I think this issue is related to the language server, yesterday I saw a prompt from in the bottom right of vscode which said "Restart language server" and then my intellisense started working but today when I started my computer, its again showing the below error and the intellisense is not working. Also as soon I opened vscode today, in the terminal it was showing that it is downloading .NET 7 or something like that. I have tried restarting the .NET language server using the command palette but it did not solve my issue.

[image]

Any kind of help is highly appreciated, thank you so much. If more information(like some logs or anything) is required to troubleshoot the issue, I will be more than happy to provide.

Comment: Dev Kit issues should be reported to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues. You might find existing threads and solutions there.

Comment: @LexLi Hi, thanks for replying. Yes I have found that an issue corresponding to my problem is already opened on the github repository you provided, but it was opened 3 weeks ago and has not been solved yet. Although I have found a workaround to solve my issue which is to basically uninstall C# dev kit, hit reload, install it again and then a prompt comes up to restart the language server, clicking on that makes the intellisense work again.

Comment: @LexLi It appears that somebody has already created a bug for it https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/917

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just disable or uninstall the C# dev kit extension and restart VSCode, everything starts working just fine.

I have not yet managed to find a permanent fix for this, although I have found a workaround to solve my issue which is to basically uninstall C# dev kit, hit reload, install it again and then a prompt comes up in the VSCode bottom right which shows an option to restart the language server, clicking on that "restart language server" makes the IntelliSense work again. I have discovered that I have to do this every time I restart my computer.